# Lifecycle start() never invoked for sub-flows during dynamic (manual) flow registration

Tags: spring-integration

I'm using dynamic (manual) registration of IntegrationFlow (via IntegrationFlowContext), and my integration flow consists of a publish/subscribe channel with one of the subscribers being a sub-flow. It turns out the sub-flow components are never started, since the sub-flow (as the integration component of the main flow) is not added to the "lifecycles" List in the StandardIntegrationFlow constructor, which only checks for AbstractEndpoint and EndpointSpec instances:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
StandardIntegrationFlow(Set<Object> integrationComponents) {
    this.integrationComponents = new LinkedHashSet<Object>(integrationComponents);
    for (Object integrationComponent : integrationComponents) {
        if (integrationComponent instanceof AbstractEndpoint) {
            this.lifecycles.add((Lifecycle) integrationComponent);
        }
        else if (integrationComponent instanceof EndpointSpec) {
            BeanNameAware endpoint = ((EndpointSpec<?, BeanNameAware, ?>) integrationComponent).get().getT1();
            this.lifecycles.add((Lifecycle) endpoint);
        }
    }
}
```

When StandardIntegrationFlow start() method is invoked, all components of the main flow are started, but not of the sub-flow. Subsequently, EventDrivenConsumer's start() method is not invoked and the MessageHandler (in my case) never gets subscribed to publish/subscribe channel.

I believe the problem lies in the code above.

Here is the test case which demonstrates this beheviour (versus the behaviour of statically defined flow):

```
@ContextConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@DirtiesContext
public class SubflowTests {

@Autowired
public IntegrationFlowContext integrationFlowContext;

@Autowired
public IntegrationFlow staticFlow;

@Autowired
private PollableChannel result;

@Test
public void testStaticFlow() {
    integrationFlowContext.messagingTemplateFor("staticFlow").send(new GenericMessage<String>("test"));

    Message<?> receive = this.result.receive(1000);
    assertNotNull(receive);
    assertEquals("test", receive.getPayload());
}

@Test
public void testDynamicFlow() {
    integrationFlowContext.register("dynamicFlow", flow -> flow
            .publishSubscribeChannel(p -> p.subscribe(f -> f.handle(new BridgeHandler())
                    .channel(result))));

    integrationFlowContext.messagingTemplateFor("dynamicFlow").send(new GenericMessage<String>("test"));

    Message<?> receive = this.result.receive(1000);
    assertNotNull(receive);
    assertEquals("test", receive.getPayload());

}

@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public static class ContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow staticFlow() {
        return flow -> flow
                .publishSubscribeChannel(p -> p.subscribe(f -> f.handle(new BridgeHandler())
                        .channel(result())));
    }

    @Bean
    public PollableChannel result() {
        return MessageChannels.queue().get();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/106.

Consider do not use sub-flows until we figure out the solution for them.

That really was expected to have some flaws with the new feature.

Comment: Thanks. Currently as a workaround, right after dynamic context registration I'm fetching beans of EventDrivenConsumer type from the context and manually invoking start() on them (since those are the only ones I need to start in my case).

Comment: Hi again, I'm using spring-integration-java-dsl:1.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT where this was fixed, however I noticed another (lifecycle-related) issue: when removing the flow via IntegrationFlowContext.remove(), the Lifecycle.stop() is not invoked on the removed flow, where I believe it should be (I'm experiencing hanging components like Pollers etc, after flow removal).

Comment: I think that is a good catch: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/issues/112 ! As a workaround you should `stop()` flow manually before calling `destroy()`.